# python 3 - match and append dicts based on key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Given a very large list, called `tsv_data`, which resembles:

```
{'id':1,'name':'bob','size':2},
{'id':2,'name':'bob','size':3},
{'id':3,'name':'sarah','size':2},
{'id':4,'name':'sarah','size':2},
{'id':5,'name':'sarah','size':3},
{'id':6,'name':'sarah','size':3},
{'id':7,'name':'jack','size':5},
```

And a separate list of all unique strings therein, called `names`:

```
{'bob','sarah','jack'}
```

The aim is to produce the following data structure:

```
[
    {'name':'bob','children':
    [
    {'id':1,'size':2},
    {'id':2,'size':3}
    ]
    },
    {'name':'sarah','children':
    [
    {'id':3,'size':2},
    {'id':4,'size':2},
    {'id':5,'size':3},
    {'id':6,'size':3}
    ]
    },
    {'name':'jack','children':
    [
    {'id':7,'size':5}
    ]
    }
]
```

Which is challenging for me to write a for loop to restructure as each length is different.

Is there a python solution that is robust to length of each item of `name`? Please demonstrate, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a straightforward solution.

```py
tsv_data = [
    {'id':1,'name':'bob','size':2},
    {'id':2,'name':'bob','size':3},
    {'id':3,'name':'sarah','size':2},
    {'id':4,'name':'sarah','size':2},
    {'id':5,'name':'sarah','size':3},
    {'id':6,'name':'sarah','size':3},
    {'id':7,'name':'jack','size':5}
]
names = {'bob','sarah','jack'}
expected_keys = ('id', 'size')
result = []
for name in names:
    result.append({'name': name,
                   'children': [ {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in expected_keys}
                                     for d in tsv_data if d.get('name') == name ]})
# result:
# [{'name': 'sarah',
#  'children': [{'id': 3, 'size': 2},
#   {'id': 4, 'size': 2},
#   {'id': 5, 'size': 3},
#   {'id': 6, 'size': 3}]},
# {'name': 'bob', 'children': [{'id': 1, 'size': 2}, {'id': 2, 'size': 3}]},
# {'name': 'jack', 'children': [{'id': 7, 'size': 5}]}]
```

In this solution, it iterates over the whole `tsv_data` for each `name`. If the `tsv_data` or `names` is large and you want to run fast, you could create another dictionary to get a subset of `tsv_data` by `name`.

Comment: looks promising, but I got an error "list object has no property 'get'" . trying to dig deeper, let me know if anything comes to mind.

Comment: Ah, it appears that `tsv_data` is actually a list of lists, not a list of objects as I thought. Can leave question and answer as is, but maybe add a line for the list of list case if you can. [1,'bob',2]. So only values, no keys.

Comment: In your post, `tsv_data` is a list of dict. Isn't it?

Comment: Maybe you need to rephrase your question to make it clearer. I will update after reading that. :)

Comment: Is it possible that `tsv_data` contains both lists and dicts?

Comment: All fixed, I cast each list into a dict to get it into the format as the question was phrased, now your answer works perfectly. Thanks!